# Jenkins file path as parameter

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm new in Jenkins.

I have simple maven project, where i use a method that take a file path parameter for parsing. The problem is to transfer the file.txt to Jenkis and specify its path in the mvn exec command:

```
java -Dexec.mainClass = test.App-Dexec.args = "path file which was add in Jenkins"
```

How can I determine the path of an uploaded file and put him into args parameter(`-Dexec.args = ?`)?

Answer (score 0):

So, i found solution. When we upload file, in the box "File location" to write the name of the file(not file location) and it is specified in the parameter test.App-Dexec.args. It's simple.